# XML: Check if anything exists between two nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to find out if anything exists between two nodes. My XML looks like this:

```
<event value1="1" value2="2" value3="3" info="some info here">
          Line 1.<lb/>
          Line 2.<lb/><lb/>
          Line 3.<lb/>
          Line 4.<lb/>
</event>
```

My goal is to convert the `<lb/>` nodes to `<br/>` HTML tags using XSLT. There is one additional requirement to fulfill though. In case there is one `<lb/>` **directly** following another `<lb/>` I want to output only **one** `<br/>`.

My XSLT looks like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="lb">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::lb[1])">
       <br/>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

The problem with the XSLT above is that it works correctly for line 1 only as the text between both nodes is ignored.

Maybe someone here can help.

Comment: Should this even work?> This isn't valid xml.

Comment: @sebastian, I tried to edit the XML so it makes sense, please edit it again if it is wrong.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a completely "push style" solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: Another, more efficient way is this:

```
<xsl:template match="lb">
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::lb)]">
        <br/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Try this:

```
 <xsl:template match="lb">
   <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id(preceding-sibling::text()[1]/following-sibling::lb[1])">
     <br/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Basically this checks if you are on the first `<lb/>` the previous text sibling node, which also means that it will only add `<br/>` after some text, but not if the `<lb/>` are at the beginning of the parent tag.

Comment: This does not seem to work. As far as I know it would but only if text was in its own note.

Comment: This is a good start but it will fail for more than two consecutive `<lb>`s.

Comment: @Tomalak, how so? I just tried both my solutions and they both work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for something along the lines of this:

```
<!-- per default, <lb> gets removed (empty template)... -->
<xsl:template match="lb" />

<!-- ...unless it is directly preceded by a non-blank text node -->
<xsl:template match="lb[
  normalize-space(preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]) != ''
]">
  <br />
</xsl:template>
```

This handles any arbitrary number of `<lb/>` nodes that may occur consecutively.

Behavior for `<lb/>` nodes that follow an element (not a text node) must still be defined. Currently they would be deleted. If you want to keep them, write an appropriate template for them.

Comment: I wonder why it hasn't been accepted !? +1 for compact solution.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lb"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "lb[not(following-sibling::node()[1][self::lb])]">
  <br />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<event value1="1" value2="2" value3="3" info="some info here">
          Line 1.<lb/>
          Line 2.<lb/><lb/>
          Line 3.<lb/>
          Line 4.<lb/>
</event>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<event value1="1" value2="2" value3="3" info="some info here">
          Line 1.<br/>
          Line 2.<br/>
          Line 3.<br/>
          Line 4.<br/>
</event>
```

**Do note**:

1. The use and overriding of the *identity transform*.
2. How `<lb>` elements are deleted by default.
3. How only the last `<lb>` element in a group of adjacent sibling `<lb>` nodes is processed in a more special way -- is replaced by a `<br />` element.